# What ever happened to Henry Pym?

Tags: marvel, avengers, avengers-vs-x-men

This question came about from the AvX story line and whether all current Avengers were going to be in this fight. I also remember that at some point he was kicked out for alcoholism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Dr. Henry Pym, also known as Ant-man, Giant Man, Yellowjacket and the Wasp (after the death of his ex-wife Janet Van Dyne) is currently running [Avengers Academy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avengers_Academy) in the former headquarters of the West Coast Avengers in Palo Verdes, California. He is back to using the moniker and powers of Giant Man.**

His current objective is to train the next generation of heroes and try to prevent as many of them as possible from becoming villains. After the events of the Civil War, Pym realized new metahumans needed training and monitoring. Since he was not really inclined to engage in superheroics, he felt he was best suited for this kind of behind the line duties.

Wikipedia references his current whereabouts:

> When Norman Osborn is defeated, Pym creates Avengers Academy, a
>   program to help train young people whose newly acquired powers were
>   manipulated by Osborn. While telling the recruits they are being
>   trained to become heroes, the truth is that their profiles indicate
>   they are the most likely to become villains and Pym hopes to prevent
>   that. Pym returned to his Giant-Man identity in Avengers Academy #7.
>   Henry Pym later joins up with the Secret Avengers.

The Academy staff includes [Giant Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Pym), [Jocasta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jocasta_%28comics%29), [Justice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vance_Astrovik), [Speedball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedball_%28comics%29), [Quicksilver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksilver_%28comics%29) and [Tigra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tigra).

[image]